# Overheating problem and reduced charge

Tags: iphone

A few days ago I noticed my iPhone is overheating and after a few minutes its charge was reduced to 18% from 80% while I only read some texts during that period. What's the problem?

I did find over a thousand responses to this question from Google results but I don't know which one is correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug iPhone overheating when the cause is clearly not the environment when the phone is used?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44774/how-to-debug-iphone-overheating-when-the-cause-is-clearly-not-the-environment-wh)

Answer (score 2):

When this has happened on my 3GS I would reboot it just in case.

I've never determined the cause, but it does appear to heavily use the cellular radio and the CPU to maximum power, both of which generate significant heat and reduce the battery charge significantly.

Since it happened so rarely - perhaps a few times a year - I assumed it was some weird iOS glitch and I chose not to pursue it any further.

If it's happening to you more than a few times a year, though, I'd take it in and have it replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like faulty hardware (battery or device itself).  There never a reason for that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Restore the software a set up as new, ie. blank and retest.